# Private Beta Badge

Tags: support, beta, badges

I have noticed that there is a badge specifically for private beta users / helpers.

[image: Beta]

Many of us have actively helped out in the beta but none have got this badge.
Can any of the SE mods help us on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These have now been granted!

[37 Users earned this badge](https://islam.stackexchange.com/badges/30/beta)

Comment: Thanks!!!!!! :)

Comment: Yay! New Beta badge to add to my collection! LOL

Comment: how do i get that :)